# My watermark is dispalyed in single image only in loop PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, watermark

I have spent days trying to make this work. I have an e-commerce site that sells houses, vehicles, lands, and rents them too.  I am trying to upload multiple images at once. Images are saved successfully but every time watermark is added only in the first Image instead of all images. I am missing something and doing stupid code with a configuration array.   image_lib package is in autoloaded files.

This is the references

**Seller Controller**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
 class SellerController extends CI_Controller {
       public function __construct(){
           parent::__construct();
           $this->load->model('ViewModel');
        $this->load->model('CommonModel');
                $this->load->model('SellerModel');
                $this->load->model('UploadModel');
                        $this->load->model('webapp/CategoryModel','CategoryModel');
                        $this->load->model('webapp/SellerModel','WebappSellerModel');
            }
     public function sellerlandsubmit()
        {
                $time = time();
                $files =  $_FILES['selllandimage'];
                $file_count = count($files["name"]);
                for($i = 0; $i < $file_count; $i++){
                    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/sell/land';
                    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpeg|jpg|png';
                    //$fileName = 'sellhouse'.$time;
                    $name = 'sellland'.time().$files ['name'] [$i];
                    $_FILES ['selllandimage'] ['name'] = $name;
                    $_FILES ['selllandimage'] ['type'] = $files ['type'] [$i];
                    $_FILES ['selllandimage'] ['tmp_name'] = $files ['tmp_name'] [$i];
                    $_FILES ['selllandimage'] ['error'] = $files ['error'] [$i];
                    $_FILES ['selllandimage'] ['size'] = $files ['size'] [$i];
                    $config['file_name'] = $name;

                    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                    $this->upload->initialize($config);

                    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('selllandimage')){
                        $tempFilename = 'noimage.png';
                        echo $this->upload->display_errors();
                    }else{
                        //store the file info
                        $image_data = $this->upload->data();
                        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2'; //default value
                        $config['source_image'] = $image_data['full_path']; //get original image
                        $config['wm_type'] = 'overlay';
                        $config['wm_overlay_path'] = 'assets/new-design/img/watermark_img.png';
                        $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'bottom';
                        $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'center';
                        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
                        if (!$this->image_lib->watermark()) {

                            $this->handle_error($this->image_lib->display_errors());
                        }

                    }
                }
    }

        }
```